# Converting separate text files containing training data and its labels to ARFF format

Tags: classification, data-mining, weka

I need to perform a classification task in Weka for a dataset. The dataset contains of 3 text files `training.txt`, `label_training.txt` and `testing.txt`. The format of `training.txt` and `testing.txt` is as follows:

```
InformationID  FeatureID  Value
1                6         1.00
1               160       31.00
1               438        1.00
1               479        1.00
2              6457        2.00
2              6664        0.65
2              6761        0.46
2              6762        1.00
```

The `label_training.txt` contains the class labels for the training data and each row represents a data point in the training set.

```
1
1
1
-1
1
-1
-1
```

Does this mean row 1 of `label_training.txt` file corresponds to all rows in the `training.txt` file which has InformationID 1? I would like to make sure if I am understanding it right. So one data point in the training set corresponds to InformationID 1 with values of 4 features with ID 6,160,438,479?

Now, how do I create an ARFF file which combines the training data and the labels for it to derive a classifier? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that your dataset is in an sparse format in which `InformationID` identifies the instance, and `FeatureID` identifies the feature, being `Value` the value for each couple of instance/feature.

Lets us assume that the `label_training.txt` is explicit (an instance is identified by the line, for example line #1 identifies instance #1, which corresponds to `InformationID` 1.

In this case, you need to generate ARFF files like the following one:

```
@relation my-relation

@attribute my-class {-1,1}
@attribute 1 numeric
@attribute 2 numeric
../..

@data
{0 1, 6 1.00, 160 31.00, 438 1.00, 479 1.00}
{0 1, 6457 2.00, 6664 0.65, 6761 0.46, 6762 1.00}
../..
```

This a WEKA [sparse ARFF format](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html) in which each couple of numbers correspond to an attribute number and to its value.

I suggest to write an script to perform this transformation.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote a script to transform into a normal ARFF format, with zeros wherever the feature has no value. This is not a sparse ARFF format. Does this have any effect on the results?

Comment: If you mean taht you have used a non-sparse format like `1,0,0,0,0,0,1.00,.....` (explicit values for all attributes), it does not have effect on the algorithms in terms of effectiveness,although it may affect memory (and disk space for sure). In that case you can transform from non-sparse to sparse with the filter `weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.NonSparseToSparse`.